# webRTC: getting VAD data on WAV audio in python

Tags: python, audio, webrtc

I am trying to run the example code of `webRTC VAD` found [here](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py).

But when I feed it a *mono-16bit wave file* of just me speaking with very long pauses, it just detects the entire file to be **voiced**, and the *voiced* output `chunk-00.wav` is the entire audio file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below I have given the console output that I receive.

```
(base) gulag_dweller@Tumuls-MacBook-Pro python_transformers % python3 VAD-python.py /Users/gulag_dweller/Downloads/try_voice.wav 
sample rate is: 48000 Hz
00001111111111+(0.12)11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100011111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111110001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111-(16.22999999999986)
 Writing chunk-00.wav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an alternative method of how to get VAD data. Instead of trying to get VAD from the pre-defined method shown in the link above, I create my own function.

The function basically measures the amplitude of the wave and any sharp spike observed above the base noise level (`1.6x the base value`) is taken to mean a voiced activity. This function assumes that only 1 human is speaking and that the noise level remains relatively constant.

```
y_list=list(audio_data1) # create an immutable list of amplitude values
y_vad=[] # initialise an array
max_noise = -1.0 # put the lowest value that one can

for i in range(len(time_s)):
    t = time_s[i]

    # Variable to store the current absolute amplitude value for the given index i
    current_audio_amplitude = np.abs(audio_data1[i])
    # since at the start, some issues arise, first few seconds are padded out 
    # and for any sudden change in |amplitude| i.e. > 60% results in stopping the program 
    if t>0.2 and max_noise > 0 and current_audio_amplitude > 1.6*max_noise:
        print(t, current_audio_amplitude, max_noise)
        break
    # take the highest value of amplitude to be the max_noise
    if current_audio_amplitude > max_noise:
        max_noise = current_audio_amplitude
print('max-noise is: '+str(max_noise))

for i in range(len(time_s)):
    # for any value amplitude that exceeds the max_noise value is taken to be a voice activity
    if np.abs(audio_data1[i]) > max_noise:
        y_vad.append(1)
    # otherwise just take VAD value to be 0
    else:
        y_vad.append(0)
```